# How to search in a column for information that does not contain certain characters

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to limit my results in a query by ruling out certain characters.  For example,  Column A is always constant, but can have multiple returns in column B.  I need to rule out everything in column B that contains "WWW", but I'm not excactly sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
...
WHERE columnB NOT LIKE '%WWW%'
```

Comment: just realized what the problem was.  I didn't know the information in the table was case sensitive.  That got me the results I needed.  Thanks

Comment: @user2847496. For these situations, you might want to use UPPER(columnB) to make sure it is always in uppercase. More info [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0203adamache/0203adamache.html)

Answer (score 1):

add a where clause:

`select x.a,x.b from foo x where  x.b not like '%www%'`

i you always wanna see a column then

`select x.a, case when x.b not like '%www%' then b else null end from foo x`

hope it helps...